# How do I remove these attributes in angular based on scope value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

How do I remove these attributes if scope.foo === false?

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="space-around center">
```

I want to do this in the html code, not in my directive.

So in summary I want my app to have

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="space-around center">
some content
</div>
```

or

```
<div >
some content
</div>
```

Comment: Are those attributes angular directive attributes?

Comment: I think so, probably angular material

Comment: Then you can't just remove or add attribute, you need to recompile dom node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<div ng-init="foo=true">
  <div ng-attr-layout="{{foo?'':undefined}}row" ng-attr-layout-align="{{foo?'':undefined}}space-around center">Hello</div>
  <button ng-click="foo=!foo">Toggle</button>
</div>
```

This will toggle presence of `layout` and `layout-align` attributes on `div`.

*How it works:*

Once `foo` property in the `scope` is `false` the value of expression inside `ng-attr-XXX` is `undefined` that will tell `ng-attr-XXX` not to add `XXX` attribute to element on which `ng-attr-XXX` is defined.

**Plunker**

http://plnkr.co/edit/2Z2uZYBVt7D3ECjcLpGO?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `ng-attr`.

E.g `ng-attr-layout="{{myValue}}`
And in you controller something like `$scope.myValue = "row"`

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
<div layout="{{(scope.foo === false)?'':'space-around center'}}" layout-align="{{(scope.foo === false)?'':'row'}}">
```

What exactly are you trying to do? @SuperUberDuper

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-hide="foo === false" layout="row" layout-align="space-around center">
```

OR

```
<div ng-hide="getHidden(foo)" layout="row" layout-align="space-around center">

.controller("name", ['$scope', function($scope){
 $scope.getHidden = function(foo){
      return foo === false;
 }
}]);
```